# MCS with AWS-Lambda returns error Consistency level LOCAL_ONE is not supported for this operation. Supported consistency levels are: LOCAL_QUORUM

Tags: amazon-web-services, cassandra, aws-lambda, cql

I am using AWS Managed Cassandra Service(MCS) with AWS Lambda for my course project. I am trying to perform write operations and I am getting Response Errors from MCS stating **Consistency level LOCAL_ONE is not supported for this operation. Supported consistency levels are: LOCAL_QUORUM**. It was working fine a few days ago and I did not change anything from my Lambda function or in my MCS Keyspace. AWS Lambda and AWS MCS are hosted on us-east-2 regions. How do I solve this?
Read operations are working fine.
Screen Shot of the logs taken from AWS CloudWatch Management which describes the error for my query :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a new parameter

> { consistency: cassandra.types.consistencies.localQuorum }

to the query execution. Below is an example of the same.

Before-> Not Working

```
 addtempuser = 'INSERT into tempbotusers (mobilenumber,name,email) values (?,?,?)';
 checkaddtempuser_result = await client.execute(addtempuser,[mobilenumber,'NoName','NoEmail']);
```

After adding the new parameter -> Working

```
 addtempuser = 'INSERT into tempbotusers (mobilenumber,name,email) values (?,?,?)';
 checkaddtempuser_result = await client.execute(addtempuser,[mobilenumber,'NoName','NoEmail'], { consistency: cassandra.types.consistencies.localQuorum });
```