# InvalidQueryException: Consistency level LOCAL_ONE is not supported for this operation. Supported consistency levels are: LOCAL_QUORUM

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, cassandra, datastax-java-driver, spark-cassandra-connector

```
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import com.datastax.spark.connector._
import com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector    
val conf = new SparkConf()
          .setMaster("local[*]")
          .setAppName("XXXX")
          .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host" ,"cassandra.us-east-2.amazonaws.com")
          .set("spark.cassandra.connection.port", "9142")
          .set("spark.cassandra.auth.username", "XXXXX")
          .set("spark.cassandra.auth.password", "XXXXX")
          .set("spark.cassandra.connection.ssl.enabled", "true")
          .set("spark.cassandra.connection.ssl.trustStore.path", "/home/nihad/.cassandra/cassandra_truststore.jks")
          .set("spark.cassandra.connection.ssl.trustStore.password", "XXXXX")
          .set("spark.cassandra.output.consistency.level", "LOCAL_QUORUM")
    
    val connector = CassandraConnector(conf)
           val session = connector.openSession()
               sesssion.execute("""INSERT INTO "covid19".delta_by_states (state_code, state_value, date ) VALUES ('kl', 5, '2020-03-03');""")
session.close()
```

i amn trying to write data to AWS Cassandra Keyspace using Spark App set in my local system.
Problem is when i execute above code, I get Exception like below:

> "com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.InvalidQueryException:
> Consistency level LOCAL_ONE is not supported for this operation.
> Supported consistency levels are: LOCAL_QUORUM"

As you can see from the above code I have already set cassandra.output.consistency.level as LOCAL_QUORUM in Spark Conf. Also I am using datastax cassandra driver.

But when I read data from AWS Cassandra, it works fine. Also I tried same INSERT command in AWS Keyspace cqlsh. It is working fine there too. So Query is valid.

Can someone help me how to set consistency via datastax.CassandraConnector?

Comment: Possible duplicate?  Does this help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60943631/mcs-with-aws-lambda-returns-error-consistency-level-local-one-is-not-supported-f

Comment: @Aaron I tried that already It does not help since datastax java driver does not support a second argument for setting consistency. Check the doc [here] (https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/Session.html#execute-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-). The second argument can only be used for binding query values to a prepared query statement . Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: So the document you referenced was written in 2015.  I guess it's relevant if 2.0 is the version of the driver you're using, but I seriously hope you're using one newer than that.

Comment: @Aaron Managed to crack this with application.conf. Find my answer below

Answer (score 4):

Cracked it.

Instead of setting cassandra consistency via spark config. I created an application.conf file in src/main/resources directory.

```
    datastax-java-driver {

        basic.contact-points = [ "cassandra.us-east-2.amazonaws.com:9142"]
    advanced.auth-provider{
        class = PlainTextAuthProvider
        username = "serviceUserName"
        password = "servicePassword"
    }
    basic.load-balancing-policy {
        local-datacenter = "us-east-2"
    }

    advanced.ssl-engine-factory {
        class = DefaultSslEngineFactory
        truststore-path = "yourPath/.cassandra/cassandra_truststore.jks"
        truststore-password = "trustorePassword"
      }

    basic.request.consistency = LOCAL_QUORUM 
    basic.request.timeout = 5 seconds 
    
}
```

and created cassandra session like below

```
import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.config.DriverConfigLoader
import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.CqlSession

val loader = DriverConfigLoader.fromClassPath("application.conf")
val session = CqlSession.builder().withConfigLoader(loader).build()
sesssion.execute("""INSERT INTO "covid19".delta_by_states (state_code, state_value, date ) VALUES ('kl', 5, '2020-03-03');""")
```

It finally worked. No need to mess with spark config
Doc for Driver Config https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/4.0/com/datastax/oss/driver/api/core/config/DriverConfigLoader.html#fromClasspath-java.lang.String-

datastax configuration doc https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.6/manual/core/configuration/reference/

Comment: Nice!  I’m glad you figured this out.  Thanks for coming back and posting your solution!